# How to set domain to avoid overlapping dots and axis in d3 plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a simple scatter plot in d3 (similar to this one from [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html)):

[image]

I use `extent()` to set the scale's input domain range.

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(xvalues));
```

Using this approach results in some dots overlapping axises in d3 plot:

[image]

How to avoid axis overlapping and make a margin similar to the matplotlib's plot?

Input values vary, so simple increment / decrement of the `extent()` output doesn't look like a general solution.

Comment: Do `xScale.nice()` after setting the domain.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Can't see any difference. It looks like nice() tries to get nearest round value and that's already 0 (zero) in my case.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I may miss something though. I tried `xScale.domain(...).nice()`, `xScale.nice()` after domain setting, and `xScale = xScale.nice()` with no luck.

Comment: Ah right. In that case D3 doesn't have anything built-in unfortunately, but you could simply multiply the min and max values by a constant to extend the axis.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff If my min is zero and I multiply it by constant I still get zero.

Comment: Ah, you find something wrong with everything I propose ;) You could also compute the range from min to max, take 10% of that, subtract it from the min and add it to the max and then `.nice()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This does the trick. Do you consider posting an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the best way of handling this is to call the scale's [`.nice()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice) function, which will round the ends of the domain of the scale to nice values. In your particular case, this doesn't work, as the values are "nice" already.

In this case I would compute the extent of the domain and extend it by a fraction of that. For example:

```
var padding = (xScale.domain()[1] - xScale.domain()[0]) / 10;
xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] - padding, xScale.domain()[1] + padding]).nice();
```

Comment: Are you missing `.domain()` in `xScale()[0]`?

Comment: Yep, and square brackets for the `.domain()`... Fixed that!

Answer (score 0):

In your matplotlib image, the dots are not overlapping and the x scale has negative value.

In d3:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([
                    d3.min(data, function(d) {
                      return d.val;
                     })-10, //so the domain is wider enough for the zero value

                     d3.max(data, function(d) {
                      return d.val;
                     }),
             ])
              .range([height , 0])
```